# preg_match - Why two identical items in matches

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$str = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/the-big-junky-map-url-with-lat-lon-etc-etc" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$matches  = array();
preg_match('/src\=\"((.*?))\"/i',$map, $matches);
echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);die();
```

I want to extract the URL from `src` attribute. And I get following in `$matches`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/the-big-junky-map-url-with-lat-lon-etc-etc"
    [1] => https://www.google.com/maps/place/the-big-junky-map-url-with-lat-lon-etc-etc
    [2] => https://www.google.com/maps/place/the-big-junky-map-url-with-lat-lon-etc-etc
)
```

I got what I needed, but why are there two identical items at [1] and [2]? How can I avoid this?

Comment: `((.*?))` 2x capturing groups == 2x result elements

Comment: you should use `$str` at `$map`.

Comment: @Rizier123, You are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `$map`, use `$str` at `preg_match('/src\=\"((.*?))\"/i',$map, $matches);`. Stop using `double capturing group` of your result.

**Try this**

```
$str = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/the-big-junky-map-url-with-lat-lon-etc-etc" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$matches  = array();
preg_match('/src\=\"(.*?)\"/i',$str, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/the-big-junky-map-url-with-lat-lon-etc-etc"
    [1] => https://www.google.com/maps/place/the-big-junky-map-url-with-lat-lon-etc-etc
)
```

Comment: Why should OP *use this*? What did you changed? Why did you changed it?

Comment: @Rizier123, I add some description about the result.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra set of parenthesis around `.*?`. They define a capturing group, and now you have a capturing group in a capturing group, hence two same results.